# Retain \n as plain text instead of new line in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have an existing text file with multiple lines. I am trying to build a bash script that concatenates all these lines into one single line delimited by **\n (actual text and not new line)** to pass it as a field in JSON file for an API to consume.

Source file:

```
abc=123
def=456
ghi=789
```

Expected output:

```
abc=123\ndef=456\nghi=789
```

Whatever I tried is either removing trailing new lines or returning same output as source file. Is it possible to tell script to treat `\n` plain text instead of new line? Appreciate any inputs as I am not able to find anything helpful online.

Comment: Please edit your question: Can you post some examples of the code you have tried and did not work? This site is here to help you, but as it stands this post reads like a coding request. If you can post some examples the better chance members of the community can come along and help you.

Comment: Be aware that some versions of `echo` will convert escape sequences (e.g. translating `\n` into an actual newline), so that may be confusing the issue. When in doubt, use `printf '%s\n' "$variable" instead.

Comment: When you say "_literal text_" do you mean the two characters backslash `\ ` and `n`?

Comment: @roaima, That is correct. wanted to retain '\' and 'n' as text values in the file. Kamil Maciorowski's solution worked for me.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, you are right. Echo was translating the output to actual line. I ended up using printf with Kamil's solution below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short `perl` solution to the problem

```
perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>); print join ("\\n", @a), "\n"'
```

You can feed it from *stdin* or supply files on the end of the command

Example

```
( echo one; echo two; echo three ) |
    perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>); print join ("\\n", @a), "\n"'

one\ntwo\nthree
```

That example is memory-bound as it will read its entire *stdin* into memory before writing it out. If you have an extremely large file you may prefer a looped approach. The same rules apply for reading input as above.

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { print "\\n" if $a++; chomp; print }; print "\n"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Two sed's action can help you.

```
$ cat file.txt
abc=123
def=456
ghi=789

sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g; s/..$//' file.txt
abc=123\ndef=456\nghi=789
```

First change newline to characters "\n", second remove extra characters "\n" at the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/$/\\n'` will add literal `\n` at the end of every line. Then you need `tr -d '\n'` to remove actual newline characters.

If the last line of your input file is not terminated by a newline character then `sed` may or may not process it. If the last line is properly terminated then our `sed` will add `\n` there as well. Your example shows you don't want `\n` at the end; therefore we need to modify our `sed` command slightly. The two commands together will be like:

```
<input sed '$ ! s/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n'
```

Because our `tr` removes all newline characters, there will be no terminating newline character in the output. If you want one then simply run `echo` afterwards:

```
<input sed '$ ! s/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n'; echo
```

If you want to capture the output with `$()` then note it removes all trailing newline characters; so in this case the additional `echo` makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks @Kamil Maciorowski. Your solution worked for me. This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried several ways to achieve this using awk but was unsuccessful.

I apologize for delayed response as I was away for couple of weeks. I have accepted your answer but it is not showing up here as I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: Looks like the way echo was treating this text also caused some confusion.